# MVVM with N-Tier

Tags: mvvm

I'm not sure with the implementation of my project using mvvm,  I have this project structure which is a project separated

- ProjTitle.Ui.Wpf
- ProjTitle.ViewModel
- ProjTitle.Bal
- ProjTitle.Dal
- ProjTitle.Bo
- ProjTitle.Common

Bo is just the dataobject , Dal will deal with Db, Bal will get the data processed by Dal, and do things such as: computation,business rules,Simple linq, etc.

I'm not using helper for Dal, I think this is an old fashion way of processing/getting data from database.

Sometimes, Bal is kinda redundant for simple function but it really helps with for some operation

Is this implementation is not a bad practice?

Comment: Take a look at DDD's layers' names http://public.dm1.livefilestore.com/y1p9s4mmvLVHmarhY-F9Wm7LczaDp41UYGLXVyfh5t9RXy0VslJFfPJgE_f1muuLm5fpNtRmxiA2BKi-Xh1XhCsOg/DDD_NLAYER_ARCHITECTURE_SMALL.png?rdrts=39432083

Answer (score 0):

You should implement it in the following way:

WPF Prj:
 - Views
 - ViewModel & Commands
 - Helpers

DAL Prj:
  -EF Model
  -Services classes

BLL:
   - Process your DAL applying some business logic

Facade:
   - allowing you to talk to your BLL->DAL

And finally your Facade is gonna be used by the Commands of your ViewModel